# How do I test a constructor in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

pingPongGame.js

```
class PingPongGame {
    constructor(winningPoints) {
        this.playerOneScore = 0;
        this.playerTwoScore = 0;
        this.winningPoints = winningPoints;
    }

    get playerOneScore() {
        return this.playerOneScore;
    }

    set playerOneScore(newPlayerOneScore) {
        this.playerOneScore = newPlayerOneScore;
    }

    get playerTwoScore() {
        return this.playerTwoScore;
    }

    set playerTwoScore(newPlayerTwoScore) {
        this.playerTwoScore = newPlayerTwoScore;
    }

    get winningPoints() {
        return this.winningPoints;
    }

    set winningPoints(newWinningPoints) {
        this.winningPoints = newWinningPoints;
    }
}
```

pingPongGame.spec.js

```
describe("when the pingPongGame constructor is called", function () {
    it("should create a ping pong game with given arguments.", function () {
        let newPingPongGame = new PingPongGame(10);
        expect(newPingPongGame.getWinningPoints).toBe(10);
    });
});
```

When I run the above Jasmine test, I get the below error.  I think that I might need to mock something, since it looks like there's some sort of recursion.  Does anyone have suggestions on how to properly test the constructor?

```
when the pingPongGame constructor is called > should create a ping pong game with given arguments.
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
    at PingPongGame.set playerOneScore [as playerOneScore] (file:///C:/Users/charl/Documents/WebDev/PingPongScorekeeper/src/pingPongGame.js:13:29)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing a stack overflow because the names of the instance properties and the getters/setters are identical. You need to use a different name for your internal properties to use this approach. The convention is generally to prefix the name with a `_` like so...

```js
class PingPongGame {
    constructor(winningPoints) {
        //...
        this._winningPoints = winningPoints;
    }

    //...

    get winningPoints() {
        return this._winningPoints
    }

    set winningPoints(winningPoints) {
        this._winningPoints = winningPoints
    }
}
```